# R read an URL table with a free text column

Tags: r, url, readline, read.table

I would like to read a txt table inside an URL. The table does have 3 columns; the second column is a character column with few words in it with quotations around words. The data cannot be accessible by public, that is why I cannot give the link here, but I give an example of how data look like when you open the http link:

```
col1  "column second" 
col3
1 "a city name" 2323
20 second 4343
30 "third row" 43434
```

'col1','"column second"','col3' are column names and this is how the header looks like in the real URL. I tried few read functions such as read_delim(), readline(), read.table and fread, but none of them could read the data correctly. When I download or copy/paste in a file, it works without any problem, but fails when I want to read directly from the URL. The problem is with the "" in the second column. For example, if I set sep=" ", the first row of the data has 5 columns, the second row 3 columns and 3rd row 4 columns.

I appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scan` to read in the data into a character vector `s` and reform all but the first 3 elements into a matrix and then data frame `DF` using those 3 elements as the column names.  Finally convert the types of each column of `DF`.  We have used `scan` to read from `Lines` shown in the Note at the end but it can also read from a file or connection using the `file=` argument of `scan`.  No packages are used.

```
s <- scan(text = Lines, what = "", quiet = TRUE)
DF <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(tail(s, -3),, 3, byrow = TRUE)), s[1:3])
DF[] <- lapply(DF, type.convert)
```

giving:

```
> DF
  col1 column second  col3
1    1   a city name  2323
2   20        second  4343
3   30     third row 43434
```

### Note

Input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- 'col1  "column second" 
col3
1 "a city name" 2323
20 second 4343
30 "third row" 43434'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfect for files, but gives 0 rows when the data is in URL.  s <- scan(text = url, what = "", quiet = TRUE) returns only url link.

Comment: As stated in the answer you must use the `file=` argument.

Comment: I changed to file=url. It can make connection with url, but it looks it goes to html content and returns more rows (number of columns Ok). For example please see the head(s): "<!DOCTYPE"    "html>"        "<html"        "lang=\"en\">" "<head>"  "<meta"

Comment: Clearly it is not going to work if you don't have a raw data file as stated n the question. .  Here is an example of reading data from a URL using scan :: `u <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/archived_data/archived_daily_case_updates/02-12-2020_1020.csv";
scan(u, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Grothendieck is perfect. I just found another solution, https://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-data-from-an-online-source/, for those who migh interest in reading url tables.

```
library(RCurl)
# The url link provided in the comment by Grothendieck
url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID- 
    19/master/archived_data/archived_daily_case_updates/02-12-2020_1020.csv'
myfile <- getURL(url, ssl.verifyhost=FALSE, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
mydat <- read.csv(textConnection(myfile), header=T)
head(mydat)
```

[image]

The problem with my url, in the question post, was that the data was not in a raw format; like a file in onedrive or google drive. It can go in another question; or please welcome to share your answers or link here, to read such type of data.